# how to know if we have received something with a DatagramPacket or not?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, datagram

I'm implementing a client-server program, and wanted that my client, after waiting 5 seconds without an ACK-Answer from server, sends back the same packet...

I made it like this, so please tell me if it's okay..

```
dp = new DatagramPacket(packet , packet.length , host , port);
        sock.send(dp);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time < 5000) && ack_dp.getLength() == 0) {
            sock.receive(ack_dp);
        }

        if (ack_dp.getLength() == 0)
            sock.send(dp);
```

so my program will wait 5 second of the ACK, if he doesnt receive anything, he will resend the same packet. I check if he received an ack or not with the packet length.. if it stays 0, then he hasnt received anything.. if it will be longer than 0, then out of the while-sequence and send a new packet.. (ps: ack_dp is 2bytes)

Answer (score 5):

`receive()` on the socket will by default block, so your loop doesn't make sense here (even if the socket was set to non-blocking, it's a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup> to busy-wait in 99.99% of the cases).

Use [`setSoTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)), and catch `SocketTimeoutException` instead.

Comment: is it the case with UDP Sockets too? I wasn't sure of this point, if UDP receive-sockets' block if they don't receive anything..

Comment: Yes, it blocks. Please Read The Fine Manual - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)

Comment: and how can I see if my packet is empty or not? is it ok with packet_name.getLength() ?

Comment: You get an exception if timeout expires with no input on the socket. And it is possible to send empty UDP datagrams - they are not empty on the wire, but at least 28 bytes - 20 bytes for IP header and 8 bytes for UDP header.

Comment: Oracle has moved the docs around leading to broken links. Updating @NikolaiNFetissov's link for public void receive(DatagramPacket p)  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)